# XDocument.Parse preserving whitespace when not asked to

Tags: c#, xml, whitespace, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to load an XDocument from a string, which contains XML elements with excessive whitespace in their text nodes. From my understanding of the MSDN for the [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx) method, it's supposed to not preserve whitespace.

Why then, in this simple example, is whitespace still present?

```
string xml = "<doc> <node>this  should  be  collapsed</node> </doc>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.Element("node").Value);
```

The result of the Console.WriteLine call is the phrase with two spaces between each word. I expected only one space between each.

Comment: I think it's "NOT" preserving the whitespace between elements, but not inside a Text Node (i.e. Text Nodes consisting of ONLY whitespace are crunched)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Not preserving whitespace" means that any text nodes that contain *only* whitespace will be ignored while loading the `XDocument`.

Your xml string can be represented by the following tree:

```
 doc
 |--#text - " "
 |--node
 |  |--#text - "this  should  be  collapsed"
 |--#text - " "
```

If you inspect the contents of `doc.Root.Value`, you will see the string

```
"this  should  be  collapsed"
```

If you instead load the string while "preserving whitespace",

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

and again inspect the contents of `doc.Root.Value`, you will see the string

```
" this  should  be  collapsed "
```

Comment: So how would I collapse whitespace inside of text nodes that contain more than just whitespace? I'm looking for HTML-like behavior of treating all whitespace like spaces and collapsing all consecutive spaces into a single space. Is that possible with the built-in API or would I have to resort to passing every single node in every document through a custom method to do that?